# cassandra connections spikes load issue

Tags: cassandra, connection, load, latency

I am using cassandra according to the following struct:
21 nodes , AWS EC2 i3.2xlarge , version 3.11.4 .

The application is opening about 5000 connection per node (so its 100k connections per cluster) using the datastax java connection driver.
Application is using autoscale and frequently opens/close connections.
Number of connections to open at once by app servers can reach up to 500 per node (opens simultaneously on all nodes at once - so its 10k connections opens at the same time across the cluster)

This cause spikes of load on cassandra and cause reads and writes latency.
I have noticed each time connections opens/close there are high number of reads from system_auth.roles and system_auth.role_permissions.

How can I prevent the load and resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your application to work with as small number of connections as possible.  You need to have following in mind:

- Create Cluster/Session object, once at start and keep it. Initialization of session is very expensive operation, it adds a load to Cassandra, and to your application as well
- you may increase the number of the simultaneous requests per connection, instead of opening new connections. Protocol allows to have up to 32k requests per connection. Although, if you have too many requests in-flight, then it's a sign that your Cassandra doesn't keep with workload and can't answer fast enough. See [documentation on connection pooling](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/pooling/)

Comment: Thanks Alex , Question is what is cassandra's best practice for number of connections per node, or how versatile(open/close) the number of connections can be - I will set the max limit connections accordingly

Comment: the standard approach is to have 1 connection per host per app + control connection (see documentation that I linked). Regarding open/close - it's recommended to open on startup of application, and close on shutdown... Open/Close is very expensive because driver is doing a lot of initialization tasks, etc. Plus you also is losing the ability to effectively use prepared statements, because they are discarded when you close connection